# Credentials in Google developer console not loading

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform, google-console-developer

https://console.developers.google.com/project/*/apiui/credential

The credentials panel on repeatedly clicking also does not load 
( keeps loading )

I need to access the Oauth 2.0 and I am unable to because nothing is being displayed.

I have done the following
activated - google analytics api ( enabled it)

Now i need to access Oauth 2.0 and My internet connection is fast yet the credential section does not laod and all other section in the google developers age is loading .

What should I do to get this resolved ?

Comment: Had the same problem. In my case it was 404 request to https://apis.google.com/js/api.js?onload=patheon_core_resolveGapi. It turns out, apis.google.com was pointing to 127.0.0.1 for some reason in machine's hosts file. So better to check Net tab in browser's console.

Comment: Hey, i'm facing the same issue. The console in the browser shows: Refused to display 'https://apikeys.clients6.google.com/static/proxy.html?usegapi=1&jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fscs%2Fapps-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fk%3Doz.gapi.en.1_kTN-jYv-w.O%2Fam%3DwQ%2Frt%3Dj%2Fd%3D1%2Frs%3DAGLTcCMFq6oqE4bo9kdl9UywXiYeLpCGew%2Fm%3D__features__#parent=https%3A%2F%2Fconsole.cloud.google.com&rpctoken=1915611791' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[**late edit**: Other answers imply that this can be caused by browser extensions and / or security proxies (which often come with anti virus or firewall software). Please check whether you have an adblocker/privacy tool/etc. enabled - disable temporary and then try again. If this doesn't help, continue reading...]

Sounds to me like this could be resolved by filling the OAuth consent screen

```
https://console.developers.google.com/project/<yourprojectid>/apiui/consent
```

You'll need at least a product name and the email address filled.
Google recently made a change so that you cannot create credentials as long as the consent screen is not filled.
Before that change one often got cryptic errors during oauth, so this change actually makes sense.

If that doesn't help i recommend setting up another project and do a quick test with that project. Sometimes a project is not properly setup at Google in which case you'd need to contact Google's customer support.

Comment: It is a major problem. Google should add some alerts to add Project name. Showing a loading screen without any update is really confusing.

Answer (score 14):

For me, it was the [Disconnect](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/disconnect/jeoacafpbcihiomhlakheieifhpjdfeo?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog) chrome plugin.

Comment: Thanks..took me 4 hours to figure it out.

Comment: This was the one for me. Had to allow "apis.google.com" in Disconnect. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you. This was causing me issues for so long.

Answer (score 5):

In my case it was Chrome [uBlock](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ublock/epcnnfbjfcgphgdmggkamkmgojdagdnn?hl=en) extension that prevented some JS scripts to be loaded resulting in infinite loader animation.

Comment: In my case it was the AdBlock plus extension that was causing the trouble. Seems Google Developers console is not very friendly towards ad-blockers.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and it was caused by my antivirus! I have Kaspersky and for some reason, it was blocking the screen from loading. I disabled the protection from Kaspersky, re-logged to the Google account and then I could load and see the page properly. I then reactivated Kaspersky and all is now fine! Don't know why but it works! :-)

Answer (score 2):

It was AdBlockPlus for me. Remember to disable it for the google developer console!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To add. For me it was the 'Dark Mode' plugin, basically, disable plugins!

Comment: this plus adblock plus did it for me

Comment: Yes chrome extensions were blocking it

Answer (score 0):

for me it was chrome adBlock extension, seems like all blocking extensions cause this problem

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. I hit the refresh button on the browser while the credential page was still loading and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i had to disable CORS blocker plugin

Answer (score 0):

For me it was using the Brave browser (presumably some security settings there). No error when I later tried with Chrome instead.